# Access or Inject HubCallerContext outside of Hub in SignalR Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an asp-net-core project with signalR implementation. I need to extract user information from `Context.User` when a method is invoked in my hub. The problem is, when the hub being constructed `Context.User` does not contain and User information. But in the method scope, `Context.User` is just what I expected.

```cs
public class Basehub : Hub
{

    public Basehub(IUserProfileProvide userProfileProvider)
    {
        this.CurrentUser = userProfileProvider.InitUserProfile(Context); // Context.User is empty when breakpoint hits this line
    }

    public IUserProfile CurrentUser {get;}
}

public class NotificationHub: BaseHub
{

private IUserProfileProvide userProfileProvider;


    public NotificationHub(IUserProfileProvide userProfileProvider)
    {

    }

    public async Task InvokeMe(string message)
    {
        var contextUser = Context.User;
        var profile = CurrentUser;//this is empty because Context is empty in the construction phase

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("invoked",message); // Context.User is OK when breakpoint hits this line
    }   
}
```

My main goal is to inject `HubCallerCOntext` to `IUserProfileProvide` and `BaseHub` will be as clean as possible.

***My question:** How can I inject `HubCallerContext` outside of the hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is not available as yet when the constructor is invoked.

It will be populated by the time the intended function is invoked.

```
public class Basehub : Hub {
    protected IUserProfileProvide userProfileProvider;

    public Basehub(IUserProfileProvide userProfileProvider) {
        this.userProfileProvider = userProfileProvider;
    }
}
```

Deferring access to it later in the flow, like in a method when the framework has had time to properly populate the context.

```
public class NotificationHub: BaseHub {

    public NotificationHub(IUserProfileProvide userProfileProvider) 
        : base(userProfileProvider) { }

    public async Task InvokeMe(string message) {
        IUserProfile profile = userProfileProvider.InitUserProfile(Context); //context populated

        //...

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("invoked",message); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I actually modified getter of `CurrentUser ` property in the `BaseHub` to invoke `userProfileProvider.InitUserProfile(Context)` when first called. So I got rid of the redundant profile initiator in every method. But I really needed the injection support for some business needs and clean architecture

Comment: That can work as well. The injection support you seek from accessing Context in the constructor wont work because that is how they designed it.

Comment: That's a bummer. Anyway thank you for the response! Happy coding